# What is the difference of creating styles in XML file to Creating in Resources folder?

Tags: android-layout

I am beginner in android developer.So i need help to find out difference between applying style in XML to applying styles in Styles folder.Please help me out.I have tried to find out this in many ways  but i didn't get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example to clear it suppose you are using a text view and styling it in layout resource file like this

```
<TextView
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:textColor="#008"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

But if you need this type of text view in 20-30 places every time you are going to write the same for styling it instead if you write it in styles xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And then applying the style to all TextView like fallowing

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

your line of code saved code is structured if you want to change in future you need to change in only one place because A style can be applied to an individual View within a layout file or to an entire Activity or application .

Comment: do let me know if you need more help or if you understand accept my answer